# apt-get install failed and not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get

i need to install some *Prerequisites* for my buildsystem but the *apt-get install* command fails:

[log apt-get install command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABYiO.png)

My system params are (running as VM):

[uname -a && lsb_release -a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EX3Aa.png)

some hints to solve this problem would be helpful.

Best regards

Lars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really speak German, but if you have broken packages, try referring to [my answered question about broken packages.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766819/how-do-i-fix-a-lot-of-broken-packages) Hope it helps!

Comment: Awesome to hear! Glad it helped you.